# Adding (3rd party) pristine to git repository

Tags: git, github

that's what I want to do:

Adding a fork of a Github repository to my (selfhostet) repository.

Why?

Because my company will use a custom build with modifications while updating the 3rd party part of the project.

Thats the repositorystructure I want to realise:

```
                        master
                       /      \
                      /        \
                 pristine     modifications
         (3rd party source)
```

Basicly the workflow would be:

- update github fork
- pull into pristine-branch
- merge updates into master (while keeping our modifications)

Important for us is the updateability without destroying our modification or remerge them into a updated pristine.

Comment: What happens if parts of the `pristine` codebase are in constant conflict with the modifications that you guys make in the `modifications` codebase? I tried something like this at a previous company and eventually, we had to make those separate codebases because the changes diverged so much. Unless there is a coalescing of the `pristine` code and the `modifications` code at some point then this might be a losing battle. Am I understanding that right?

Comment: we would/will resolve them manually when needed (for example a new feature gets released or every 2 years ...) anyway did you manage to make this workflow work?

Comment: This might not have been the best way, but we ended up not supporting the 3rd party fork anymore. Our `modifications` fork diverged so much that we would have had to duplicate every change we made to `pristine` in our `modifications` fork. So double the work for every change in `pristine` basically. We just made it a separate project all-together and labeled it as legacy.

Comment: i see but its more that we had to sourcebuild the software were working with for different reasons and built it with other 3rd party plugins but we erally want it to be updateable the software itself and each plugin...
i really appreaciate you but a 'legacy-source' wouldnt fit our needs, we discussed it very much and thats the only option for us.
however it seems that you made it work would you be so kind to tell me how? :)

Comment: You might not be able to do what we did. Based on your situation we would have made `pristine` and `modifications` 2 totally separate repos. If the `pristine` repo needed any changes, which never really happened, then we would make the change there and maybe reproduce it in the `modifications` repo. This allowed us the freedom to go crazy with the `modifications` repo and add whatever features we wanted without worrying about how we were going to make it work in both `pristine` and `modifications`.